# Use regular expressions on vim to fnd and replace all href links content to '#'?

Tags: regex, vim, macvim

Is it possible to use vim to replace the 'http://google.com/' and other links to '#'?

```
 <a class="link1" href="http://google.com/">My Link</a>
 <a class="link1" href="http://yahoo.com/">My Link</a>
 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">My Link</a>
```

to

```
 <a class="link1" href="#">My Link</a>
 <a class="link1" href="#">My Link</a>
 <a href="#">My Link</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one should handle the basic `http` case:

```
:%s/http:\/\/[^\"]*/#/g
```

But this should be more flexible - the general idea is to find instances of `href="`, save that as a group, then match until we hit another `"`. Then we replace it with our group (`\1`) and the hash sign:

```
:%s/\(href=\"\)[^\"]*/\1#/g
```

Comment: noob follow up question... how do I enter commands? I am on mac vim

Comment: @user1530249 On normal Vim, you hit the `:` (I'll add that into the answer so it is more obvious). That puts you in command mode, after which you would enter that command.

Comment: You should find a basic `vim` tutorial and work through it.  To answer your question, hit the `:` key to bring up the command line in vim.

Comment: Agree with @steveha - Vim is incredibly powerful, but it can be a bit overwhelming at first. Find a good tutorial (even try typing `vimtutor` at a command prompt) and you'll be well on your way to wishing everything had a Vim interface :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks, great answer. I will work through a tutorial and learn more about regex. Thanks

Comment: @user1530249 No problem at all, good luck with everything. Vim is a ton of fun, so you've got good times ahead :)